# Disable warmup text/make it less distracting

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Is there any way to make the big "WARMUP 1:33" in warmup rounds on Competitive less distracting or remove it completely? I'm looking for clientside commands (ones that only appear on my end.) and not ones for my own server. I play MM regularly and I find it big and distracting. Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it without hiding the rest of the HUD

Answer (score 1):

There is no way currently to remove the command from the center of the screen, but you can use the command cl_draw_only_deathnotices 1 which will remove the hud and not your crosshair or killfeed.

if this doesn't work then you can try cl_drawhud 0.

To undo either of these commands, just change the number from a 1 > 0 or 0 > 1.

if neither of these remove the timer then there currently isn't a way to remove it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -5):

The only current command to do so, is `mp_warmuptime 0`, and this can only be achieved by hosting the server yourself.

Comment: doesn't that command completely remove the warmup round? which does  not seem to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @ColinD While you are correct, this is the only thing that can remove the warmup time, as there is no probable clientside command.